# Switch statement (string) keeps selecting default value unless its zero

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++, switch-statement

Switch statement only works when I change the value between the brackets to 0 in cout << getDayOfWeek(0);.
Any number between 1-6 selects the default value "Invalid Day Number".
There isn't any issues (no issues found).
I tried retyping it from scratch and nothing worked.
The code is supposed to print out the day when I enter its number, but it only works with 0. If I put other numbers, it selects the default value.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include <string>

#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

    string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum) {
    string dayName;

    switch (dayNum) {
    case 0:
        dayName = "Sunday";
        break;

        switch (dayNum)
    case 1:
        dayName = "Monday";
        break;

       switch (dayNum)
    case 2:
        dayName = "Tuesday";
        break;

        switch (dayNum)
    case 3:
        dayName = "Wednesday";
        break;

        switch (dayNum)
    case 4:
        dayName = "Thursday";
        break;

        switch (dayNum)
    case 5:
        dayName = "Friday";
        break;

        switch (dayNum)
    case 6:
        dayName = "Saturday";
        break;

    default:
        dayName = "Invalid Day Number";
    } 

    return dayName;
}

int main()
{
    cout << getDayOfWeek(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't repeat `switch (dayNum)` over and over; keep only the first one, remove all the others. As written, your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: also don't use [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `switch` statement incorrectly. The code should look like this:

```
switch(dayNum){
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something
        break;
    case 3:
        // do something
        break;
    case 4:
        // do something
        break;
    case 5:
        // do something
        break;
    case 6:
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

You shouldn't repeat the `switch` statement over and over again; just keep the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You won't need `switch (dayNum)` inside the `switch` statement.
They will create nested `switch` statements and leave only `case 0` and `default` in the first `switch` statement.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include <string>

#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

    string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum) {
    string dayName;

    switch (dayNum) {
    case 0:
        dayName = "Sunday";
        break;

    case 1:
        dayName = "Monday";
        break;

    case 2:
        dayName = "Tuesday";
        break;

    case 3:
        dayName = "Wednesday";
        break;

    case 4:
        dayName = "Thursday";
        break;

    case 5:
        dayName = "Friday";
        break;

    case 6:
        dayName = "Saturday";
        break;

    default:
        dayName = "Invalid Day Number";
    } 

    return dayName;
}

int main()
{
    cout << getDayOfWeek(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the `switch` statement by using an array:

```
static const char day_names[] =
{
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
};

const std::string day_of_week = day_names[dayNum];
```

The `switch` statement adds more lines of code to your project, which increases complexity and the probability of defects.